# index out of bounds: 1 (java) when passing a string paramater through a method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception

The program is designed to error check other source files, by matching up the opening bracket with the closing bracket. Because I want to use the program each time I'm error checking code, I've created an array that will store the lines of code feed through the scanner and then have a method that then converts it into a string, but when I try to store the new string and pass it through another method that will take it apart and check for the opening and closing braces, it crashes and the stack shows an out of bounds error. I've tried to fix this multiple times, but I can't figure out what is causing it to crash.

Here is what I have so far. Can I get any help?

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at MatchUp.arrayToString(MatchUp.java:51)
at MatchUp.main(MatchUp.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class braceMatchup{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{


  Scanner nameDoc = new Scanner(System.in);                              
  System.out.println("Please enter the file name:");
  String fileName = nameDoc.next();                                                        
  File validation = new File(fileName);

  while (!validation.exists()){                                           
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid file name:");
    fileName = nameDoc.next();
    validation = new File(fileName);
  }

  nameDoc.close();

  Scanner doc = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));                    
  arrayToString(doc);  
}


public static void arrayToString(Scanner doc){

  for(int tLines = 0; doc.hasNextLine(); tLines++){
    String lines[] = {doc.nextLine()};

    for(int pLines = 0; pLines <= tLines; pLines++){
        String arrayLine = lines[pLines].toString();

        walkArray(arrayLine, tLines);}
    }
}

public static void walkArray(String arrayLine, int tLines){
 int index;            

  for (int i = 0; i <= arrayLine.length(); i++){
    if (arrayLine.substring(i) == "{" || arrayLine.substring(i) == "}")
      index = i;
    else
      index = arrayLine.length();

    bracketCount(arrayLine, index);
  }
}


public static void bracketCount(String arrayLine, int index){

  int openCount = 0; 
  int closeCount = 0;          


  if(arrayLine.substring(index) == "{"){
    openCount++;

    if (index != 0){
      String formatLine = arrayLine.substring(0, index -1); //lines[pLines].indexOf('{')
      System.out.println(formatLine.trim() + " " + "(" + openCount + ")" + "{");}

      else if(index == 0){
        String formatLine = arrayLine.substring(index); //arrayLine.indexOf('{')
        System.out.println(formatLine.trim() + " " + "(" + openCount + ")" + "{");
      }
      else if(arrayLine.substring(index) == "}"){
        closeCount++;

        if(openCount > closeCount)
          closeCount = openCount - 1;
        else if(closeCount > openCount)
          closeCount = 0; 

      if(index != 0){
        String formatLine = arrayLine.substring(0, index - 1); //arrayLine.indexOf('{')
        System.out.println( formatLine.trim() + " " + "}" + "(" + closeCount + ")");
      }
      else if (index == 0){
        String formatLine = arrayLine.substring(0, index - 1); //arrayLine.indexOf('{')
        System.out.println( formatLine.trim() + " " + "}" + "(" + closeCount + ")");}
      }
      else
        System.out.println(arrayLine);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that arrays are 0 base indexed.

Comment: Can you post the error trace?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing an error trace, it's hard.. but looking @

```
public static void arrayToString(Scanner doc){

for(int tLines = 0; doc.hasNextLine(); tLines++){
  String lines[] = {doc.nextLine()}; // SINGLE ELEMENT ARRAY

  for(int pLines = 0; pLines <= tLines; pLines++){
      String arrayLine = lines[pLines].toString(); // if pLines > 0, you'll be sad

      walkArray(arrayLine, tLines);}}}
```

The problem is most likely when accessing `lines[pLines]`.  I have no idea what your logic is attempting (I didn't read that far... just did a code review), so you should probably re-evaluate this.

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at MatchUp.arrayToString(MatchUp.java:51) at MatchUp.main(MatchUp.java:27) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:27‌​2)

Comment: pLines is a value that would increment after a line was converted to a string, that would change witch portion of the array was converted next

Comment: The `lines` array you are referring to is a single element array.  I.e. it has a length of 1 and the only valid index is 0.  Trying to access any other index will result in the exception you see.